# Broadleaf - Offer Controller endpoint

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Do we have offer controller which has offers endpoints? We need to fetch the offer details of the product. Is there any api or endpoints available to display the offer information

Answer (score 0):

The Broadleaf Offers API does not have an endpoint to determine all the products that it applies to. Offers only apply once you add them to your cart, and because Offers are normally used with rules, you would have to iterate the entire catalog (not suitable for large catalogs) to determine if each product applied.